# Is it possible to recieve the geo information collected by iOS in my app?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I need to implement a module in my app which is like a geo spy (like ios), so I need to collect the information about most visited places, geotracking, etc. I know that iOS is spying in background for this geodata. Is it possible to get this data for using in my app?

Comment: you can't make it in spy mode. iOS may allows to you spy. But app review team will not allow your app into sale.

Answer (score 1):

the location data are logged in consolidated.db and i believe you can't read them programmatically. The location data are not precise and will be stored only for 7 days.

read more: [How to See the Secret Tracking Data in Your iPhone](http://www.pcmag.com/article2/0,2817,2383943,00.asp)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the visits API in Core Location - See `startMonitoringVisits` in [CLLocationManager](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CLLocationManager/startMonitoringVisits)

There was also some information on the visits API in a WWDC video from this year.